# Selecting Pandas dataframe records based on the content of a series field

Tags: pandas

========================  UPDATE  #2  =============================================

What a day.  I am very slowly making progress.  But while PANDAS is very fast and powerful it has a steep learning curve and there are not very good examples (at least for what I am trying to do).

The latest issue is with a specific line:

```
 catfile = infile[infile['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: any(targetcat in x))]
```

which works in IPyNotebook, but not under Ubuntu and python 2.7

here is the error on Ubuntu:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "scikit2.py", line 27, in <module>
        catfile = infile[infile['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: any(targetcat in x))]
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.11.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/series.py", line 2408, in map
        mapped = map_f(values, arg)
      File "inference.pyx", line 861, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:41822)
      File "scikit2.py", line 27, in <lambda>
        catfile = infile[infile['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: any(targetcat in x))]
    TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

and the working code + results in iPyNotebook

```
targetcat = 'Financial Services Industries'
#targetcat = 'Payroll & Employment Tax'
criterion = foo[foo['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: any(targetcat in x))]
print criterion[['dtu_docid','dtu_topic_split']][:10]



     dtu_docid                                    dtu_topic_split
9    2010-0185                    [Financial Services Industries]
17   2010-0152  [Financial Services Industries, International ...
46   2012-1421  [Financial Services Industries, Payroll & Empl...
49   2012-1413  [Financial Services Industries, Payroll & Empl...
66   2012-1370  [Energy Taxation, Financial Services Industrie...
94   2009-1786                    [Financial Services Industries]
144  2012-1170       [Financial Services Industries, Real Estate]
163  2012-1101       [Financial Services Industries, Real Estate]
170  2009-1386                    [Financial Services Industries]
249  2012-0754  [Expatriate Taxation, Financial Services Indus...
```

Here is the python version for iPYNotebook

```
print sys.version
2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3]
```

and from Ubuntu:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01) 
[GCC 4.7.3]
>>>
```

Need help.  I am sure I could be done with this data set-up and grooming if I used traditional processing.  Still trying PANDAS but this is tough sledding and the saddest part is I am not even sure why the stuff I got to work, works.  These type of errors breed frustration

========================  UPDATE  #1  =============================================

Using the info in the 1st answer (thanks tshauck) I have found one way to accomplish the issue:

```
targetcat = 'International Taxation'
criterion = foo[foo['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: any(targetcat in x))]
```

This yields a list of rows where the targetcat is in the dataframe.dtu_topic_split series.  Given I am new to panda is this the best way to handle.  My intention it to build separate training modules for each of the 30-50 categories.  I am unsure if I should iterate over the approximately 100K records in more traditional python style, or use the pandas technique.  Again any alternatives or advise would be greatly appreciated.

---

I am new to Pandas and struggling to learn how to make use of the powerful capabilities. I posted yesterday with a strategy to solve this problem by building a separate dataframe. After reading more I am not sure it is the most efficient.  I have tried several techniques to slect specific rows form a datafarame based on the existance of a specific value in a series field of the dataframe.  Below is an sample of the data and my attempts.

```
print foo[['dtu_docid','dtu_topic_split']]

/home/davidwaldrop/Dropbox/Miscelaneous/E&Y M&C Project/scikit training
   dtu_docid                                    dtu_topic_split
0  2012-1553          [Energy Taxation, State & Local Taxation]
1  2012-1552         [Legislation & Policy, Financial Services]
2  2010-0227            [Quantitative Economics and Statistics]
3  2010-0215                     [International Taxation, Asia]
4  2012-1529  [Ernst & Young Newsletters, This Week in Tax R...
```

And here is what I am working on now, to no avail:

```
targetcat = ['International Taxation']

criterion = foo['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda x: x == targetcat)

print foo[criterion]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, dtu_docid, dtu_topic, dtu_content, dtu_topic_split]
Index: []
```

What I want is a dataframe containing the records where 'International Taxation' is in the series stored in the field dtu_topic_split, or in the above example the record in foo[3] with a dtu_topic_split value of [International Taxation, Asia].

As I mentioned I am really trying to learn Pandas and think it very powerful.  As a newbie it is very difficult to not only find a way to do what I want, but also the best way along with the rational.  My instinct tells me this may best be done with indexing, but I have not even gotten to that feature yet.  Any insight is most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I'm understanding your particular use-case well enough to provide a decent answer.

Given some data:

```
data = """
dtu_docid|dtu_topic_split
9|2010-0185|['Financial Services Industries']
17|2010-0152|['Financial Services Industries', 'International']
46|2012-1421|['Financial Services Industries', 'Payroll & Employment Tax']
49|2012-1413|['Financial Services Industries', 'Payroll & Employment Tax']
66|2012-1370|['Energy Taxation', 'Financial Services Industries']
94|2009-1786|['Financial Services Industries']
144|2012-1170|['Financial Services Industries', 'Real Estate']
163|2012-1101|['Financial Services Industries', 'Real Estate']
170|2009-1386|['Financial Services Industries']
249|2012-0754|['Expatriate Taxation', 'Financial Services Industries']
""".split('\n')
```

And with this question in mind:

> "What I want is a dataframe containing the records where 'International
>   Taxation' is in the series stored in the field dtu_topic_split"

You might get it into a DataFrame

```
rows = [row for row in data if len(row) > 0]

cleaned = []
for i, row in enumerate(rows):
    row = row.split('|')
    if i == 0:
        headers = row
    else:
        row = row[1:] # get rid of the index
        row[1] = eval(row[1])
        cleaned.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned, columns=headers)
```

Which looks like this:

```
print df
   dtu_docid                                    dtu_topic_split
0  2010-0185                    [Financial Services Industries]
1  2010-0152     [Financial Services Industries, International]
2  2012-1421  [Financial Services Industries, Payroll & Empl...
3  2012-1413  [Financial Services Industries, Payroll & Empl...
4  2012-1370   [Energy Taxation, Financial Services Industries]
5  2009-1786                    [Financial Services Industries]
6  2012-1170       [Financial Services Industries, Real Estate]
7  2012-1101       [Financial Services Industries, Real Estate]
8  2009-1386                    [Financial Services Industries]
9  2012-0754  [Expatriate Taxation, Financial Services Indus...
```

Now you have this awkward `dtu_topic_split` column that's a python list. That a little tricky to deal with.

To select rows with one item you're interested in, you can `apply` a `lambda` function. For example:

```
print df.dtu_topic_split.apply(lambda x: 'Energy Taxation' in x)
```

That'll give you a boolean series.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: dtu_topic_split, dtype: bool
```

And you can then pass that to `df[...]` via sub notation.

```
energy = df[df.dtu_topic_split.apply(lambda x: 'Energy Taxation' in x)]

print energy
   dtu_docid                                   dtu_topic_split
4  2012-1370  [Energy Taxation, Financial Services Industries]
```

Another way to go that might work better is to get your data into [long format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data).

Going back to the `cleaned` variable (a list of lists), you could write a little function that "stacks" rows that have more than one topic.

```
def make_long(cleaned):
    lng = []
    for row in cleaned:
        # row is a list of length 2
        topics = row[1] # second item is the list of topics
        dtu_docid = row[0]
        for topic in topics:
            lng.append([dtu_docid, topic])

    return lng
```

In this case, `cleaned` was 10 rows long. When you call `make_long`, you end up with 17 rows, as any row having more than 1 topic appearing more than once.

```
make_long(cleaned)
Out[208]: 
[['2010-0185', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2010-0152', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2010-0152', 'International'],
 ['2012-1421', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-1421', 'Payroll & Employment Tax'],
 ['2012-1413', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-1413', 'Payroll & Employment Tax'],
 ['2012-1370', 'Energy Taxation'],
 ['2012-1370', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2009-1786', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-1170', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-1170', 'Real Estate'],
 ['2012-1101', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-1101', 'Real Estate'],
 ['2009-1386', 'Financial Services Industries'],
 ['2012-0754', 'Expatriate Taxation'],
 ['2012-0754', 'Financial Services Industries']]
```

Then you can stick that into a dataframe and you should be in business.

```
lng = pd.DataFrame(make_long(cleaned),
    columns=['dtu_docid', 'dtu_topic_split'])

print lng
    dtu_docid                dtu_topic_split
0   2010-0185  Financial Services Industries
1   2010-0152  Financial Services Industries
2   2010-0152                  International
3   2012-1421  Financial Services Industries
4   2012-1421       Payroll & Employment Tax
5   2012-1413  Financial Services Industries
6   2012-1413       Payroll & Employment Tax
7   2012-1370                Energy Taxation
8   2012-1370  Financial Services Industries
9   2009-1786  Financial Services Industries
10  2012-1170  Financial Services Industries
11  2012-1170                    Real Estate
12  2012-1101  Financial Services Industries
13  2012-1101                    Real Estate
14  2009-1386  Financial Services Industries
15  2012-0754            Expatriate Taxation
16  2012-0754  Financial Services Industries
```

This way you can select rows by one or several topics at a time using the `isin` method on the `pd.Series` object.

```
selected = ['Financial Services Industries', 'Real Estate']
print lng[lng.dtu_topic_split.isin(selected)]

    dtu_docid                dtu_topic_split
0   2010-0185  Financial Services Industries
1   2010-0152  Financial Services Industries
3   2012-1421  Financial Services Industries
5   2012-1413  Financial Services Industries
8   2012-1370  Financial Services Industries
9   2009-1786  Financial Services Industries
10  2012-1170  Financial Services Industries
11  2012-1170                    Real Estate
12  2012-1101  Financial Services Industries
13  2012-1101                    Real Estate
14  2009-1386  Financial Services Industries
16  2012-0754  Financial Services Industries
```

Hopefully some of this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact cause of your issues, but one thing that stands out to me is that you're comparing the exact equality of two lists... when (if I understand) you want to compare the presence of your `targetcat` in `dtu_topic_split`... which I guess is list of topics.

Assuming that's the case something like the following may work:

```
targetcat = ['International Taxation']

criterion = foo['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda possiblecat: \
    any([t in p for t in targetcat for p in possiblecat]))
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it'll return true if any category in `targetcat` is contained in any substring of a category in `possiblecat`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried, it but it returns True for everything.  I will analyse the map section of the statement, as this is the part most confusing to understand about this specific issue, and Pandas in general.  Thanks again.  here is what I got as results:                                                                       
criterion = foo['dtu_topic_split'].map(lambda possiblecat: any([t in p for t in targetcat for p in possiblecat]))

print criterion

print foo[criterion]

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
Name: dtu_topic_split, dtype: bool
      id  dtu_docid